# PySDL2 and SDL_FreeSurface

Tags: python, sdl-2, pysdl2

I'm using PySDL2 and while reading the examples, I noticed that the examples call `sdl2.SDL_FreeSurface(image)`. I am wondering, if I don't use FreeSurface, does that create a memory leak? Doesn't the garbage collection handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It creates a memory leak, if the surface is not managed by some high-level wrapper (e.g. the SoftwareSprite/TextureSprite objects found in the pysdl2.ext package http://pysdl2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/sdl2ext_sprite.html).

The SDL2 functions and structures of PySDL2 are plain 1:1 wrappers to the C library, so there is no automated garbage collection.